# How to solve a Diophantine equation in six variables?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Find all the integer solutions $a, b, c, d, e, f$ satisfying the equation $a^2b^3 + c^2d^3 = e^2f^3$.

Note that if we prove that there are no such solutions with the condition $\text{gcd}(ab, cd, ef) = 1$ and $|bdf|>1$ then we get simpler proof of Fermat's last theorem, because each positive integer $n>1$ has a representation $n=2k+3l$.

Comment: As you say, this is harder than proving the modularity of elliptic curves.

Comment: $a=2,b=1,c=11,d=1,e=1,f=5$

Comment: $100+243=343$ ($a,b,c,d,e,f=10,1,3,3,1,7$). $1+675=676$.

Comment: $3125+4563=7688$ ($a=5,b=5,c=13,d=3,e=31,f=2$).

Comment: @ThiKu I think you do not really need full modularity of elliptic curves over Q for Fermat's theorem; I think it was proved after Fermat's theorem has been proved. Or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 1):

Some solutions with $a,b,c,d,e,f>1$:
$$ \eqalign{3125 + 4563 &= 5^3 \cdot 5^2 + 3^3\cdot 13^2 = 7688 = 2^3\cdot 31^2\cr
4563 + 66125 &= 3^3 \cdot 13^2 + 5^3\cdot 23^2 = 70688 = 2^3\cdot 94^2\cr
45125 + 49923 &= 5^3 \cdot 19^2 + 3^3\cdot 43^2 = 95048 = 2^3\cdot 109^2\cr
19773 + 100352 &= 13^3 \cdot 3^2 + 8^3\cdot 14^2 = 120125 = 5^3\cdot 31^2\cr
25947 + 105125 &= 3^3 \cdot 31^2 + 5^3\cdot 29^2 = 131072 = 32^3\cdot 2^2\cr
41503 + 144500 &= 7^3 \cdot 11^2 + 5^3\cdot 34^2 = 186003 = 3^3\cdot 83^2\cr
15125 + 204363 &= 5^3 \cdot 11^2 + 3^3\cdot 87^2 = 219488 = 38^3\cdot 2^2\cr
78125 + 141376 &= 5^3 \cdot 25^2 + 4^3\cdot 47^2 = 219501 = 29^3\cdot 3^2\cr
66125 + 199712 &= 5^3 \cdot 23^2 + 2^3\cdot 158^2 = 265837 = 13^3\cdot 11^2\cr
61504 + 224939 &= 4^3 \cdot 31^2 + 11^3\cdot 13^2 = 286443 = 3^3\cdot 103^2\cr
3087 + 301088 &= 7^3 \cdot 3^2 + 2^3\cdot 194^2 = 304175 = 23^3\cdot 5^2\cr
15125 + 356168 &= 5^3 \cdot 11^2 + 2^3\cdot 211^2 = 371293 = 13^3\cdot 13^2\cr
136107 + 276125 &= 3^3 \cdot 71^2 + 5^3\cdot 47^2 = 412232 = 2^3\cdot 227^2\cr
231125 + 233523 &= 5^3 \cdot 43^2 + 3^3\cdot 93^2 = 464648 = 2^3\cdot 241^2\cr
9248 + 455877 &= 2^3 \cdot 34^2 + 37^3\cdot 3^2 = 465125 = 5^3\cdot 61^2\cr
675 + 595508 &= 3^3 \cdot 5^2 + 53^3\cdot 2^2 = 596183 = 23^3\cdot 7^2\cr
8575 + 620289 &= 7^3 \cdot 5^2 + 41^3\cdot 3^2 = 628864 = 34^3\cdot 4^2\cr
171475 + 528392 &= 19^3 \cdot 5^2 + 2^3\cdot 257^2 = 699867 = 3^3\cdot 161^2\cr
168507 + 561125 &= 3^3 \cdot 79^2 + 5^3\cdot 67^2 = 729632 = 2^3\cdot 302^2\cr
263169 + 469567 &= 9^3 \cdot 19^2 + 7^3\cdot 37^2 = 732736 = 4^3\cdot 107^2\cr
168507 + 666125 &= 3^3 \cdot 79^2 + 5^3\cdot 73^2 = 834632 = 2^3\cdot 323^2\cr
30375 + 830297 &= 15^3 \cdot 3^2 + 17^3\cdot 13^2 = 860672 = 8^3\cdot 41^2\cr
}$$